# How to say I miss home?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

I am studying abroad now, and one day I went to a dinner that celebrating Chinese New Year and it brings all my memory of how I used to celebrate with my family.

Can I say that "It was a great night that recalls all my memories I spent with my family in Chinese New Year? "

1.Is that other way to say it that would sound more like a native speaker

2.memory or memories?

AND

How can I say I am really looking forward to back to my home to celebrate it since I'm a student that don't allow me to flight back home in that period of time.

Thank you, guys!!!!

Comment: Fixed type: aboard -> abroad.

Comment: I wish I were back home celebrating the new year with my family.  OR: I can't wait to be back in (town) celebrating the new year.

Comment: Proofreading questions are off topic because they do not help anyone but the asker. The only exception is when there is a clearly identified source of concern about an element of the English language that would be interesting and useful to many future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel down because you miss your home, you are said to be *homesick*.

Homesick via [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homesick)

> Longing for home and family while absent from them : "He was homesick when he went to college."

For you're phrase, I'd rephrase it as "It was a great night that recalls all my memories *where I spent Chinese New Year with my family.*"

It would be "memories" as you're presumably speaking about multiple different events, which are multiple different memories. You recall things from your *memory*, but your individual events which you recall are *memories*.

Answer (score 1):

You would say you were nostalgic.

> Nostalgia
>
> a sentimental longing or wistful affection for a period in the past.
>
> Yesterday I was nostalgic about all the hours spent in the University Library

Answer (score 0):

You could say that it made you *yearn* or *pine* for your home if you were missing the festivities with your family, or that the event was *redolent* or *reminiscent* (reminding you of) the Chinese New Year with your family, in more of a fond-memory-but-still-enjoying-the-moment kind of way.

...but *homesick* could work too!